# Add a Table counting values in a Line graph

Tags: excel, graph

I have a line graph displaying a percentage of assignments completed on time vs a target percentage and I'd like to have a table below showing which group has had overdue tasks as time goes on.
So what I did was add the Data Table element and included the groups performance as multiple data series (same as Target% and Actual%) but this only shows 0s rather than the values of the cell while also treating it as more inputs for the line graph.

Is there a way to do what I want?

[image: Here's how it looks now.]

Comment: You probably want to use a combo chart

Comment: Yup, that did it, Thanks!